# X "feet" long - Measurement unit

Tags: terminology

I'm curious on the measure unit "foot/feet".  We all have a ruler that tells you how long is 1 foot/2 feet long.  But why using the word "foot/feet"?  I am assuming it's how long an average human's feet - where 1 foot long means basically your foot's length.  Am I correct on this?  And if so, it seems people from the past have much larger feet?

Comment: This curiosity should really be slaked on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=where+did+the+term+foot+come+from+for+measuring) first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily or unluckily, I have large feet, and actually they measure bang on a foot (well give or take a centimetre or two - I still use a ruler rather than my feet to measure things!).

You correctly surmised that there is a connection between the measurement and human feet. A few websites [tell us this](http://www.factmonster.com/ipka/A0769529.html). (Note that in the linked article, it mentions that the size of a foot has changed over the years)

It is also logical if you think about it. Before modern, more accurate measurement instruments existed, humans relied on themselves to give measurements. We still measure horses in hands to this date.

[Here is a bit of further reading that I found interesting.](http://www.npl.co.uk/educate-explore/factsheets/history-of-length-measurement/)

Comment: Thank you!  I do have feet that's a BIT off, so I am not sure if there's other origin to the terms and now it's clear.  I have to say there's nothing unluckily with large feet, other than shoes might cost more in general

Comment: Many historical units refer to the human body. The "hand", the "cubit", and the "finger" are all examples. @Alex

Comment: @mstorkson And "digits".

Comment: Let us not forget the "rule of thumb".  :-)